# Setting Projects to Private by Default

Tags: sonarqube

I have my SQ server running in Kubernetes (via Tectonic) and all is going well. We need to tighten the security of our SQ installation, so we have LDAP up and working. We are trying to get all of the projects to be Private by default (which we can do Via the GUI for each project).

However, trying to flip the switch in the GUI to make all new projects Private works, until you refresh the page, then it reverts back to Public.

I have been searching for a way to set this up via the sonar.properties file or sonar-project.properties file (first if the preferred). The server.properties file we use is encrypted as a secret (because the LDAP settings exposes a service account password) and I would like to keep settings there.

I have combed through documentation, posts, discussions and all that, but have not been able to find out what the **value=key** combination is.

Has anyone seen what this is or if we can even accomplish that? Is it a setting stored in the database? I'm kind of at a loss on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: I managed to capture an error in the browser console: https://pastebin.com/7VXYgEVE

Answer (score 4):

In SonarQube 7.x you can find the public/private setting when you browse to Administration - Projects - Management. This only works for new projects. For existing projects you can use the "Edit the permissions" option on the same page and switch between public and private.

[image: SonarQube 7.1 (Admin)]

You can also use the web_api to achieve the same results. You can find the documentation when you add "/web_api/api/projects" after the sonarqube URL:

[image]

Example of the POST request body: project=MyProject&visibility=private

Comment: Thanks, but this option does not work for me since I click on making all NEW projects Private, but as soon as I navigate off the page and check again (or refresh the page), the setting reverts back to the Default of Public.

This is why I am trying to look for it in a properties file.

Comment: Do you get a confim-popup after activating the "Default visibility of NEW projects" setting on the page shown above?

Comment: I click on the pencil, select Private, click Change Default Visibility and it changes. When you go to another page (even in SQ) and come back, it is set back to public. No other dialog boxes. No Errors. Nothing in the logs.

Comment: Did you check the network call using the F12 tools for example?

Comment: @JeroenHeier SonarQube 7.1 gives me "Unknown url : /api/organizations/update_project_visibility" when I try to change the default visibility

Comment: @Alexey This link: https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/projects succeeds. The local SonarQube version should provide the same option; this feature was introduced in SonarQube 6.4.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I know, but in 7.1 there is a regression bug, it was confirmed. For some reason, we don't get new Docker images for SonarQube, so we have now stuck with 7.1 and this bug before we deploy a local instance without Docker and it is much more work than using the Docker version.